"Update dataspace" message on Android Studio console
I am facing this issue in Android Studio, it does not affect me directly but it is too annoying because if I have to print something on console, it get lost in multiple lines of message that is thrown when I tap on android screen. For reference I am using Redmi 13C for testing my apps.
Message on Console
I/gralloc4(31985): @set_metadata: update dataspace from GM (0x00000000 -> 0x08010000)
I/gralloc4(31985): @set_metadata: update dataspace from GM (0x00000000 -> 0x08010000)
I/gralloc4(31985): @set_metadata: update dataspace from GM (0x00000000 -> 0x08010000)
I/gralloc4(31985): @set_metadata: update dataspace from GM (0x00000000 -> 0x08010000)
I/gralloc4(31985): @set_metadata: update dataspace from GM (0x00000000 -> 0x08010000)
I/gralloc4(31985): @set_metadata: update dataspace from GM (0x00000000 -> 0x08010000)
I/gralloc4(31985): @set_metadata: update dataspace from GM (0x00000000 -> 0x08010000)
I/gralloc4(31985): @set_metadata: update dataspace from GM (0x00000000 -> 0x08010000)

I could not figure out how this message occurs but for single tap this same message appears on console multiple times.

These logs are so annoying. To get rid of it, you can remove it from the logcat by adding this to the filter:
package:mine -message=:"@set_metadata: update dataspace from GM"


These are just debug logs of the various operations that happen while you navigate through your application/device
These are not bugs or problems, just records
In fact, if it's annoying for you, you can just remove it by right-clicking and selecting 'fold lines like this', as shown in the photo:


I am using terminal and still it spams in there, how should I fix it there

This works for me:
package:mine level:info -message:@set_metadata

Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1
